# cons operator (::) in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

The :: operator in F# always prepends elements to the list. Is there an operator that appends to the list? I'm guessing that using @ operator

[1; 2; 3] @ [4]

would be less efficient, than appending one element.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As others said, there is no such operator, because it wouldn't make much sense. I actually think that this is a good thing, because it makes it easier to realize that the operation will not be efficient. In practice, you shouldn't need the operator - there is usually a better way to write the same thing.

**Typical scenario:** I think that the typical scenario where you could think that you need to append elements to the end is so common that it may be useful to describe it.

Adding elements to the end seems necessary when you're writing a tail-recursive version of a function using the *accumulator parameter*. For example a (inefficient) implementation of `filter` function for lists would look like this:

```
let filter f l = 
  let rec filterUtil acc l =
    match l with 
    | [] -> acc
    | x::xs when f x -> filterUtil (acc @ [x]) xs
    | x::xs -> filterUtil acc xs
  filterUtil [] l
```

In each step, we need to append one element to the accumulator (which stores elements to be returned as the result). This code can be easily modified to use the `::` operator instead of appending elements to the end of the `acc` list:

```
let filter f l = 
  let rec filterUtil acc l =
    match l with 
    | [] -> List.rev acc                        // (1)
    | x::xs when f x -> filterUtil (x::acc) xs  // (2)
    | x::xs -> filterUtil acc xs
  filterUtil [] l
```

In (2), we're now adding elements to the front of the accumulator and when the function is about to return the result, we reverse the list (1), which is a lot more efficient than appending elements one by one.

Comment: Surely there is a way to do this w/o the need to reverse the array at the end?

Comment: If you wanted to do this without reverting the list, you could use the implementation described by Norman Ramsey or use a mutation (in F#, you'd have to define mutable list). Using standard list type, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Could you please explain why reversing is "a lot more efficient than appending elements one by one"?

Comment: Because a nonempty singly linked list is a constructor with one value (the head), and a pointer to another linked list (the tail). To get the last element in a list that you haven't accessed before, you have to follow as many pointers as the number of elements in the list.

Appending at the front just means constructing a new list with the element you want to append, and a pointer to the old list. Appending to the end of a list requires either mutating the last constructor in the list, or making a new list where you copy every element in the old list.

Comment: You explained why appending to the end is bad (which I already knew), but you didn't explain why reversing is "a lot more efficient". I suspect the `list` type in F# is a doubly linked list, so the reversing operation is just to update some internal flag.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Could you please explain why reversing a list is more efficient?

Comment: @Mihir I'm only just starting F#, but I believe it is because if you are appending to an immutable list it will need to walk the entire list each time it 'appends' an item to the end and creates a new list. By prepending to the front of the list, you always have a pointer to the beginning of the list, then to reverse the list, you only need to walk the entire list 1 time.

Answer (score 35):

Lists in F# are singly-linked and immutable.  This means consing onto the front is O(1) (create an element and have it point to an existing list), whereas snocing onto the back is O(N) (as the entire list must be replicated; you can't change the existing final pointer, you must create a whole new list).

If you do need to "append one element to the back", then e.g.

```
l @ [42]
```

is the way to do it, but this is a code smell.

Comment: snoc ? And are you suggesting appending to a list is a bad idea ? In which case, how would you build up a list incrementally ?

Comment: @Brian Agnew, you build it up at the front, then List.rev when you've finished (see Tomas's answer). Unfortunately, I'm not clever enough to tell you how many O()'s that makes.

Comment: @Benjol - that makes sense and is what I do in Scala. Thx.

Comment: @Brian Agnew: it's a pun: `"snoc" == "cons".reverse`

Comment: @Benjol: Well, building the list initially requires one cons for each element, and the reverse operation does a fold over that list, once again doing one cons for each element. This means there's 2n cons operations needed to build a list of length n in such a manner. However, in big-O notation the constant factor of 2 is irrelevant here, so the task of building a list in such a manner is O(n).

Comment: `1@[42]` doesn't compile. perhaps `1::[42]` was what you were looking for?

Answer (score 15):

The cost of appending two standard lists is **proportional to the length of the list on the left**.   In particular, the cost of

```
xs @ [x]
```

is proportional to the *length of `xs`*—it is **not** a constant cost.

If you want a list-like abstraction with a constant-time append, you can use John Hughes's function representation, which I'll call `hlist`.  I'll try to use OCaml syntax, which I hope is close enough to F#:

```
type 'a hlist = 'a list -> 'a list   (* a John Hughes list *)
let empty : 'a hlist = let id xs = xs in id
let append xs ys = fun tail -> xs (ys tail)
let singleton x = fun tail -> x :: tail
let cons x xs = append (singleton x) xs
let snoc xs x = append xs (singleton x)
let to_list : 'a hlist -> 'a list = fun xs -> xs []
```

The idea is that you represent a list functionally as a function from "the rest of the elements" to "the final list".  This works great if you are going to build up the whole list before you look at any of the elements.   Otherwise you'll have to deal with the linear cost of append or use another data structure entirely.

Comment: I can smell something funny.. I think it's my brain melting :)

Answer (score 4):

> I'm guessing that using @ operator [...] would be less efficient, than appending one element.

If it is, it will be a negligible difference. Both appending a single item and concatenating a list to the end are `O(n)` operations. As a matter of fact I can't think of a single thing that `@` has to do, which a single-item append function wouldn't.

Comment: Before appending a list with a @ operator one needs to create a list of one element.

Comment: @Max: How would you implement an append function which did not create a single-element list containing the appended item? After all the tail of the tail of the tail of `[1,2,3,4]` is `[4]`. And you can't construct a list without constructing its tail.

Comment: Remember what it actually means to have a list: It means you have `a :: b :: c :: d :: []`.  In order to append a new element to the end, you have to construct `a :: b :: c :: d :: e :: []`. And as was illustrated earlier, `e :: []` is the same thing as `[e]`. On the other hand, to prepend an element to a list, it's just `e :: original_list`.

Comment: -1 : as pointed out by Brian, since F# lists are singly-linked, adding to the end is an O(N^2) operation where N is the length of the list.  This can become quite substantial for large lists.  Much better to prepend as you build the list, then List.rev when returning the final result, which is O(N).

Comment: @JamesHugard: Appending to a list is *not* `O(N^2)`. Appending N times is `O(N^2)`. Appending to a list once is `O(N)` which is the same as concatenating a list of length 1 to the end of the list. Yes, prepending is faster (because it is `O(1)`), but that was NOT the question. The question was whether concatenating a single item list to the end was slower than appending a single item. Which it's not.

Comment: I stand corrected, and tried to remove the downvote (can't because it is too old).  However, the answer may be misleading to some.  Adding a single item, ONE TIME, will not be very expensive: O(N), where N is the original list size. BUT, lists are generally iteratively built in N operations and would therefore cost O(N^2), where N is the number of items to put in the list.

Comment: Also, I'm not clear on the difference between "appending" and "concatenating" a single element; aren't they synonymous?

Comment: @James: O(N) is certainly slow for adding an item to the list. And yes concattenating a one-item list and appending an element are the same sematically. The question was whether a function that knew it was only appending a single element would be faster than using `@` with a single element list. Which it's not.

Comment: @JamesHugard : That seems like it'd be a massive oversight on MS's part if that's how it's done. Everything in F# being immutable, you have to create/copy a whole new list in order to have two lists concatenated, one to the end of an older one. But a rather easy way to do it in O(n) time instead of O(N^2) would be to build the tail-list first, then the head-list, you'd then join the head's tail with the tail's head, all in O(n) (sorry for the confusing wording).

Comment: @Noein: Not an oversight by MS, but rather compatibility with OCaml; afaik, all ML-based languages define lists as singly linked (as does Haskell).  As to performance, the general solution is to reverse your list, append multiple items to the head, then reverse the list again, which makes for an order O(N) operation.  See the answer by Brian.

Comment: @JamesHugard They're singly-linked, yes. That was the implied reason for my necessitating making the tail list before the head list (the head list would just be built head's-head first, like normal, then linked to the already built tail list using the head's-tail element when it is finally constructed).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to use another data structure. We have double-ended queues (or short "Deques") in [fsharpx](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx). You can read more about them at http://jackfoxy.com/double-ended-queues-for-fsharp

Answer (score 2):

The efficiency (or lack of) comes from iterating through the list to find the final element. So declaring a new list with `[4]` is going to be negligible for all but the most trivial scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a double-ended queue instead of list. I recently added 4 versions of deques (Okasaki's spelling) to FSharpx.Core (Available through NuGet. Source code at  [FSharpx.Core.Datastructures](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/tree/master/src/FSharpx.Core/DataStructures)). See my article about using dequeus [Double-ended queues for F#](http://jackfoxy.com/double-ended-queues-for-fsharp)

I've suggested to the F# team the cons operator, ::, and the active pattern discriminator be made available for other data structures with a head/tail signature.[3](http://jackfoxy.com/my-suggestions-for-new-fsharp-language-features/)